# Как отобразить данные в datagridView из двух таблиц со связями один к одному?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

Как вывести в *dataGriedView* данные из двух таблиц со связями один к одному?

```
public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Login { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public UserProfile Profile { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserProfile
    {
        [Key]
        [ForeignKey("User")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }

        public User User { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserContext : DbContext

    {
        public UserContext() 
        :base("DefaultConnection")
    { }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Неужели только Join?

Comment: Да, только join...

Comment: @pavelip а можно было бы создать пользовательское представление, создать навигационные свойства и воспользоваться automapper

Comment: я не знаю как это сделать этим способом, не разбирался, но в том которым я решил есть недостаток, так как dataGriedView не обновляется динамически.

Comment: @Bald56rus в вопросе была описана модель для ef. С ней по другому нельзя. А так можно написать запрос, создать процедуру или другими стопитцот способами

Comment: как теперь сделать так чтобы dataGriedView обновлялся динамически????

Comment: что Вы понимаете под "динамически"?

Comment: что бы после добавления записи dataGridView тут же её отображал.

Comment: ну так после добавления записи вызывайте обновление DataGridView. в чем проблема то?

Comment: dataGriedVieW.Refresh() или  dataGridView1.Update(); не работает!!!

Comment: в Вашем же ответе есть dataGridView1.DataSource = result.ToList() разве не работает?

Comment: Работает, но DataGriedView Обновляется только после закрытия окна, и запуска его снова.

Comment: Всё заработался. Всё работает и обновляется, нужно было просто запрос в нужное место разместить!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если нужен именно `JOIN`, то можно так

```
var result = 
(from u in db.Users
join p in db.UserProfiles on u.Id equal p.Id
select new {
    Id = u.Id,
    Login = u.Login,
    Password = u.Password,
    Name = p.Name,
    Age = p.Age
}).ToList();
```

но в Вашем случае сойдёт и так

```
var result = 
(from u in db.Users
select new {
    Id = u.Id,
    Login = u.Login,
    Password = u.Password,
    Name = u.UserProfile.Name,
    Age = u.UserProfile.Age
}).ToList();
```

или так

```
var result = db.Users.Select(u => new {
    Id = u.Id,
    Login = u.Login,
    Password = u.Password,
    Name = u.UserProfile.Name,
    Age = u.UserProfile.Age
}).ToList();
```

Если будет ошибка, то скорее всего Вам в классе надо включить подгрузку данных, для этого надо к Вашим классам приписать `virtual`, выглядит это будет так

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public virtual UserProfile Profile { get; set; }    //изменения здесь
}

public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }    //и здесь
}
```

и вовсе не обязательно бежать писать SQL-запросы))

Answer (score 0):

Отвечаю на собственный вопрос, может кому и пригодится:

```
var result = db.Users.Join(db.UserProfiles, // второй набор
              p => p.Id, // свойство-селектор объекта из первого набора
              t => t.Id, // свойство-селектор объекта из второго набора
              (p, t) => new { Age = p.Profile.Age, Name = p.Profile.Name,Login = p.Login,Password = p.Password }); // результат 
   dataGridView1.DataSource = result.ToList();
```

Так всё работает, только коду много. Какая выгода от этого Linq? 
Можно в ручную запрос писать!

Comment: Вручную - вы имеете в виду sql-запрос? Выгода от linq в статической типизации. Компилятор отловит опечатку. При изменении структуры базы данных легко будет найти все места в коде, которые нужно изменить.